# how to redirect to a page after successful login: ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to redirect to `homepage` after successful login in ReactJS? and also how to show `error message` whenever user enter wrong credential?
I tried something like below, but it not `redirect` to `homepage` after successful login and also not showing `login failed` prompt whenever user hit wrong credential.

 It would be great if anybody could figure out where i did mistake.

./src/Login.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Form} from 'antd';


export default class App  extends Component{


  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            username: "",
            password: "",
        }
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onFormSubmit(values){
      console.log(values);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("username", values.username);
      formData.append("password", values.password);

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        };

       fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', options).then(() => {
          this.props.history.push('/home')
        }).catch((error) => {
        alert('Login Failed!')
        })


    };


 render(){
    return(

      <div>
                            <Form onFinish={this.onFormSubmit}>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                    <Form.Item name="username">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                  <Form.Item name="password">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Password"/>
                                   </Form.Item>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn_3">
                                        log in
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </Form>

     </div>
```

Comment: Never use alert. Use `console.log` with your dev tools set to preserve logs instead of wiping them on navigation. Also, can you properly indent this code and finish it? (there's code missing at the end). Finally: are you using routing? (e.g. react-router).

Comment: Is this Component rendered inside a `react-router` Route that provides a `history` prop? Did you check the console for error messages? And if you want to redirect based on login success, your fetch callback should process the server's reply.

Comment: Do you add `withRouter` when exporting component? Or you can use `useHistory`.

Comment: @BeHappy i tried `useHistory`, but it's not redirecting to my `homepage` after successful login.

Comment: Does url change after successful login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component is a direct child from a  you can call this.props.history.push('/url');
If not, you can export the component like this:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
....
export default withRouter(ComponentName);
```

And then you can call this.props.history.push('/url');

To display errors you need to push errors to the state and do this in the render method:

```
{this.state.errors !== [] && (
  {this.state.errors.map(error => (
    {/*Display the error*/}
  ))}
)}
```

Comment: i didn't get what you mean

Comment: I tried also like this, but it not redirect to homepage after successful login.

Comment: do you use any remote application like teamviewer or anydesk?

Comment: No, please just share the code here or send a [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/) link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214700/discussion-between-puk-and-bounty).

Comment: you can take a look at this link--> https://pastebin.com/3CEFdKzf

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use react-router-dom, you can use

```
<Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
```

Be sure to setup a route that match the path you provided to Redirect component

Comment: i tried also this method, but it's not working also.